# smtp configuration for zend framework to connect my own domain

Tags: zend-mail

```
    I am now using zend framework and want to send email using my own domain.I set the configuration like this.How can i connect the smtp using my domain not gmail.My error is :

5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 da3sm19328626pdb.8 - gsmtp
```

My code is :
        class MailService{
            private $sender ="admin@mydomain.com";
            private $password="mypassword";

```
        public function configSmptpOptions(
        'name'=>'test',
        'host'='>mail.mydomain.com',
        'port'=>587,
        'connection-class'=>'login',
        'connection-config'=>array(
        'username'=>$this->sender,
        'password'=>$this->password,
        'ssl'=>'tls'
        )
        );

    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and elaborate your issue in detail.

Comment: i want to know is it  possible my own domain in stead of using smtp.gmail.com? I want to use the automailsender as admin@mydomain.com so how i configure my domain to smtp .